# How can I activate settings for the Equalizer in PulseEffects?

Tags: pulseaudio, equalizer

I have installed PulseEffects, but the Equalizer settings are greyed out and inaccessible.
It allows me to choose from among my previous equalizer profiles, but I cannot edit them.
I can also change settings for other PulseEffects utilities such as the Filter and Limiter.
How can I activate settings for the Equalizer in PulseEffects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this same problem, so here is the solution.

From an answer on Ubuntu MATE community forum, I learned that the [`lsp-plugins`](https://lsp-plug.in/) package (*LSP (Linux Studio Plugins) audio-plugins (metapackage)*) needs to be installed using the command

```
sudo apt install lsp-plugins
```

A reboot is needed afterwards, or just log out and log back in.

From man page (more [here](https://lsp-plug.in/?page=manuals)):

> This package provide 91 plugins.
> Audio effects: limiters, dynamic processors, expanders, gates, graphic equalisers, impulse responses, impulse reverbs, compressors, multiband compressors, parametric equalisers, phase detector, sidechain multiband compressors, sidechain limiters, sidechain dynamic processors, sidechain expanders, sidechain gates, sidechain compressors, slapback delays, delay compensators, triggers.
> Synths: samplers, and multisamplers.
> Tools: latency meters, oscillators, profiler, spectrum analyzers, and MIDI triggers
> Available as LV2, LADSPA and standalone Jack clients.

Comment: Thank you. I can now edit my equaliser settings, after I executed "sudo apt install lsp-plugins."

Comment: This solution works with Ubuntu 20.04 and PulseEffects ver. 13.99.1.